Feature Request: Audio Snippets similar to image uploads
Audio Snippets
Would it be reasonable to add the capability of small audio snippets to the Chinese Language wiki? 
The feature might take this form:

Snippets only (no more than 30 seconds long)
Able to be embedded similar to image uploads

Implications:

Probably would require an audio recording feature to be efficient

Rationale:

For a language wiki, the ability to hear samples of native speech
seems to be a no-brainer to me.

Why here:
Other websites provide audio content but no context. A language wiki seems ideal to house this material as it is highly pertinent to every visitor.
Drawbacks:
The need to not pollute the wiki with junk.
Argument in favour:
I would argue that the drawbacks are handled using current community mechanism. Technical limitations should be nil as the technology to produce the feature set already exists (see italki.com for example).

Not a bad idea.

I think we should redirect viewers to the newer, more concrete proposal Support for Soundcloud embedding
